# Did the Romans see Africa as a black continent? Was there a perception of a divide between Africa and Europe?

Tags: europe, roman-empire, africa, classical-antiquity, ancient-rome

Nowadays the Western world perceives Africa as the continent of the black people and hence a standard African person as a black individual.

How did the people in the Roman empire perceive the African continent and "its people"?

Furthermore, North Africa was under Roman control for a very long time and Carthage was a very important city. This brings another question: Did individuals within the Roman empire perceive Africa and Europe as entirely separate places, as is the case today?

If there was no divide between Africa and Europe in the social framework, then at what moment in history did people started seeing Africa as a totally separate place?

Comment: Something to remember here is that even today, North Africa and sub-Saharan (or "black") Africa are culturally & ethnically distinct.  Rome, like Greece (and the Phoenicians &c) before it, was a Mediterranean civilization with much in the way of common roots & culture. (And not much in common with the barbarians of northern Europe :-))  The Sahara was the barrier that made the rest of the continent largely a "terra incognita" until the Age of Exploration.

Comment: @jamesqf precisely the reason what it is logical to think that Romans didn't perceive North Africa to be a totally different place, although most people cannot imagine that the social framework in the past was so different to the point that North Africa and Europe could have been perceived as practically the same place by Romans.

Comment: Indeed, they certainly didn't perceive North Africa very different. Just non-Roman, but for instance the Egyptian culture *was* respected (apart from the propaganda during the war against Cleopatra). They also had no bias against *aethiopes*, black people. That's a modern thing.

Comment: I would think the conspicuous fact that there was a sea between them would make them perceive them as different places, even if there were commonalities.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: No, because the Mediterranean Sea was the center of their world.  Why do you think it has that name?  After Carthage and Egypt (which were in no sense "black") were conquered, the whole circumference  of the sea was Roman.  Outside were barbarians like the northern Europeans and Saharan peoples, the Persians, and the distant, half-known lands of India.

Answer (score 15):

You can't really compare the two, because the Romans lived in such a different world than we do.

The Romans didn't really have the concept of a "continent", as they didn't know for a fact that land past where they'd explored ever ended at all<sup>*</sup>. For all they knew, the Earth may have been half or more land, and the seas merely big lakes.

For Africa, they had two terms: *Libya* was what they called North Africa (*Africa* was originally the name of a [Roman province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa_(Roman_province)) in Libya), and *Ethiopia* is what they called the part of sub-Saharan Africa they (dimly) knew about. They did know that *Ethiopians* had really dark skin, but would have personally rarely encountered them (mostly [Nilo-Saharan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilo-Saharan_languages) immigrants from upriver on the Nile), and would have had no concept of how many such people were down there, or how far south their territory went.

Here's a 15th century [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_world_map) built from information in Ptolemey's [Geography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_(Ptolemy)) in 150CE. You can't really see the legends on it, but its legible if you [go here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/PtolemyWorldMap.jpg) and zoom.

[image]

<sup>* - Yes, the learned knew the world was round, but that doesn't mean that the landmass to the south of them wasn't connected to the landmass to the northeast, wrapped around the earth</sup>

Comment: At what point in time was Publius Cornelius Scipio awarded the epithet "Africanus"? Was it while he lived? What did that word mean to those who awarded it?

Comment: The spherical projection is, I would say, the most striking feature of the map

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Scipio Africanus was called that because of his military victories against Carthage, in North Africa.  See e.g. the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scipio_Africanus

Comment: @MichaelHardy - As I mentioned in the answer, "Africa" to them was a province in Libya. Specifically, the territory that used to belong to Carthage.

Comment: @dmckee - Hmmm, was going to credit the actual 15th Century drawer with the projection, but no it looks like that was Ptolemy's. Wikipedia is claiming (unreferenced) Europeans were doing map projections as far back as the 3rd century BCE.

Comment: @jamesqf : That that is why Scipio was called that is something I was well aware of long before I posted (indeed I was aware of it long before the world wide web existed). But it does not address the question in my comment. My question was what the word "Africa" meant to them.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: If you were aware of that, why ask the question?

Comment: @jamesqf : Because I wondered what the answer is, and I still do. Obviously "Africa" was some geographic region that included the city of Carthage, but specifically what region?

Comment: @MichaelHardy https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Roman_Empire_with_provinces_in_210_AD.png   took me a google search.

Comment: @CptEric : That map is from AD 210. What about four or five centuries earlier when Scipio was awarded that epithet?

Comment: @MichaelHardy - If there's enough to this question merit all this back-and-forth in my answer's comments (7 so far), perhaps there's enough to it to merit asking it as a proper question?

Answer (score 4):

The idea that ["Strange things come out of Africa"](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2003/02/0219_030219_outofafrica.html) originated in the Greco-Roman world.

Even then, Africa was considered a little "different" because of the strange animals such as elephants, camels and lions. These, and the Sahara desert, had no counterparts in Europe.

But Africa was not viewed as a "dark" continent. Dark-skinned Mediterraneans were more inclined to see Africans as darker versions of themselves than say, a northern European might. And no one in Europe had the idea of Africa as a continent, with jungles that they would not imagine. For all they knew, Africa might have been one or several islands like Madagascar.

The difference of Africa was seen in terms of geography, not people, in ancient times. As far as Carthage was concerned, it was seen as the current home of a group of people formerly from the Hellenic world, which helped to limit the perception of "differentness" to geography.

Comment: "Dark-skinned Mediterraneans", particularly Romans & other Italians, weren't as dark-skinned then as now.  See any number of surviving statues, frescos, &c.

Comment: I had always understood the term "dark continent" to mean that it was a continent about which little was known, rather than referring to the dark color of the skin of people living there.

Comment: "While post-Roman Italy had many waves of invaders (among others, the Goths, Lombards, Arabs, and Normans, these groups tended to replace only the upper echelons of society rather than the bulk of the population. Northern Italy is somewhat more "Germanic" than the south - but that probably reflects the ancient Gallic heritage as much as outside conquest. Southern Italy shows admixtures from around the Mediterranean. However the overall heritage of Italy is a mix of the historic inhabitants of the peninsula in Roman times." Apparently because the invasions were many but not *consistent* enough.

Comment: @Vincenzo Oliva: As I said, look at Roman era statues and paintings, and compare them to the inhabitants of the area today.

Comment: @jamesqf: Statues lost their colours. As for the paintings, I disagree. I'm Italian, many figures wouldn't be out of place today. It turns out that originally Romans were pretty white, frequently wth blonde or red hair, but in time they picked up features of Italic and Mediterranean peoples, so that you would have seen (also) "Italian" faces in the streets and in the army.

Comment: @Vincenzo Oliva: Statues lost their colors, but didn't change their shape.  The features on average seem different - more northern Europeanish - than Italians today.   The rest of what you say is pretty much what I said: there was a lot of immigration, voluntary and as slaves, from around the Mediterranean.  For just one example, a number of Jews-turned-Christians.

Comment: @jamesqf: The first emperors reflect what you say. What I'm saying is that Italians today shiuld be quite similar to the *overall* population of Italy back then, which originally was not only made up of Romans, but eventually it was.

Comment: This ethnical difference between North and South Italy is interesting and can even be perceived in the Americas. Most Italian immigrants to Brazil came from Veneto and their descendants are one of the whitest folks you can find in Brazil. While in the US the stereotype about Italians is a dark-skinned pizzaiolo with a moustache, which doesn't hold at all in Brazil. The US received the largest amount of Italians immigrants and I'd say more Southerners than Brazil.